# How to pass string from C# to delphi dll function?

Tags: c#, string, delphi, unity-game-engine, delphi-2006

so I want to use .dll file's function made from delphi.

Here is delphi's code,

```
procedure Login(login,password:PChar); stdcall;
   var
    LoginPacket:tLoginPacket;
    s:IP_bigstr;
    q,w:integer;
    pb:PByte;
   begin
    LogMessage('Login: '+login+' pwd: '+password);
    fillchar(loginpacket,sizeof(loginpacket),0);
    LoginPacket.code:=10;
    LoginPacket.lr.version:=100;
    LoginPacket.lr.protocol:=ProtocolVersion;
    LoginPacket.lr.login:=login;
    LoginPacket.lr.gameversion:=version;
    s:=password;
    EncryptPwd(s,@loginPacket.lr.pwd);
    Loginpacket.lr.pwdhash:=PasswordHash(password);
    LoginPacket.lr.gameID:=0;
    LoginPacket.lr.regname:='noname';
    LoginPacket.lr.cdkey:=0;
    LoginPacket.lr.cshash:=0;
    loginpacket.lr.sversion:='';
    pb:=@loginpacket; inc(pb);
    for q:=1 to sizeof(tloginpacket)-1 do begin
      pb^:=pb^ xor ((q+10)*(q+10) div 5);
      inc(pb);
    end;
    SendData(@loginpacket,sizeof(loginpacket));
    SimpleRequest(21,1,0);
    SimpleRequest(20,0,0);    
   end;
```

and here is my C#(unity3d) try,

```
[DllImport ("ServerTool")]
private static extern void Login([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string id, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string pass);

private static extern void Login(string id, string pass);

...
if(stage ==1){
Login("Test", "qwerty");
stage = 2;
}
```

above both definition to Login method fails,

and when running this part(if(stage==1)...Login), unity crashes and closed.

So I think this Login usage from C# has some problem with communicating delphi dll.

Please help.

Thank in advance.

Comment: Replace PChar type - it is only alias. Depending on Delphi version it would be PAnsiChar pointing to 8-bit before-unicode data or PWideChar pointing to 16-bit UCS-2 data (and which is used by Java and maybe dotnet too), not good to play guessing games in DLLs.
1: Tag your question with actual Delphi version. 2: Change function header for certain pointer type. 2.1: Turn on typed pointers ( {$T+} pragma). Might help to catch such problems, if code is not playing dirty all through. 3: Show declaration of tLoginPacket type. 4: What is "s:IP_bigstr;", is it string or what type is it ?

Comment: 5: show DLL log content.
especially after s:=password; - do log the s value.

You can also use Windows API OutputDebugString for logging.

In general better would be to declare *var s_login, s_password: UnicodeString/AnsiString/WideString;* - type depending upon Delphi version and arguments pointer type. Then with very 1st lines do *s_login := login; s_password := password;* and only use string vars ever after. And - do log and do check values of those vars!!! would they be a single-letter values, only 1st letter of every passed string ?

Comment: Like about PChar, what type is UnmanagedType.LPStr ? Is it Unicode or MBCS ? which codepage ? or is it random guess, depending on compiler options like _T macro in Visual C++ ?

Comment: hi, delphi version is, Turbo Delphi Explorer (it's Delphi 2006)

Comment: edit the question to add dlephi 2006 tag to it please.
delphi 2006 was not unicode-based, so PChar probably is PAnsiChar. But to save you on later troubles if Delphi upgraded, and to make code self-documenting, i stil lsuggest you to change them to PAnsiChar. I also suspect you only get 1 first char of new string. Please chack and implement other items from the list.

Comment: quite probably your DLL crashes itself, logging might be nice to add to get where it crashes. Does it enter the function ? which values does it get inside ? which calls does it pass before crash and which not yet.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362.aspx in DLL, 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx for you to see

Comment: What is in your dll log?

Comment: Must I use Login([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string  or just string?

Comment: Oh sorry, this Login part does not have problem, reason of unity crash was because of other part, function GetRequestResult(out code:integer):PChar; stdcall;

Comment: I used in C#, private static extern string GetRequestResult(out int code);  so this must be changed to use IntPtr, not string itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget the calling convention in C# as well:

```
[DllImport ("ServerTool.dll"), CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
```

You may also need to specify a CharSet, based on which version of Delphi you use.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7b93s42f.aspx
and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.callingconvention.aspx

Comment: hm thx for reply. I tried [DllImport ("ServerTool", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)], but fails still.

Comment: Turbo Delphi Explorer (it's Delphi 2006)

Comment: Then use `CharSet=CharSet.Ansi,`

Comment: Can you try removing all code from the dll function except for the initial logging. If the call succeeds and the logging works, the call in itself is fine, and another part of the function is causing the trouble.